# How do you disable pinch/zoom in the web browser on wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

With all other browsers you add the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
```

to disable pinch to zoom, but this does not work on wp7.

Does anyone know how to disable pinch to zoom on wp7?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I currently use this meta tag: 




?

1
 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320,user-scalable=no" />. The app has a 'bounce' when you zoom in, but it reverts back to the original size.

Answer (score 1):

long story short, check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/22/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Note the tiny font?

> *Note: In the initial release, IE Mobile for Windows Phone 7 does not support initial-scale, maximum-scale, or minimum-scale.

Also check this [other question from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972466/prevent-ie-mobile-from-scaling-web-pages-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this. Which shows the tips of using webbrowser in windows phone. Here is the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/3031e22a-e7ac-4d1e-b9e5-a627ac63f307